# What's the significance of "as" keyword in this code

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.media.SoundChannel;

    public class EmbeddedSoundExample extends Sprite
    {
        [Embed(source="smallSound.mp3")]
        public var soundClass:Class;

        public function EmbeddedSoundExample()
        {
          //WHAT DOES "as" keyword DO IN THE FOLLOWING LINE ??
          //*************************************************

            var smallSound:Sound = new soundClass() as Sound;

            //COULD BE WRITTEN AS : 
            //==>>>> var smallSound:Sound = new soundClass() ???
            // OR
            ////==>>>> var smallSound:Sound = new Sound() ???
         //******************************************************

            smallSound.play();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "as" operator is not necessary here

Comment: hmm..ok, actually i got this code from the Adobe reference: 
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Working_with_Sound_01.html

Comment: it is casting the sourdClass to Sound

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a casting operator introduced in ActionScript 3. The difference with `as` (as opposed to `Type(object)` casting) is that if the cast fails, the result will be the default value for the type. More on this [here](http://archive.darronschall.com/weblog/2006/02/actionscript-3-casting.html)

Comment: the answer above is 100% correct, however to explain it a bit more easy: soundClass is a Class, however in the code you give the value of the soundClass to a variable with type "Sound". So to catch the error you tell flex that he should see soundClass as a Sound instead of class.

Comment: Also worth noting that this type of casting _only_ works if the castor inherits from the castee. So sprite as Shape works just fine. But if you want to cast a string as a number, you have to use Number(string). You also want to use this when grabbing e.currentTarget from an event. To grab a sprite, you would do `var current:Sprite = e.currentTarget as Sprite`.

Answer (score 1):

`as` casting, use the data like the Type that your are using, no change the data.
if you use Type(object) and you can't convert to this Type, return a default value( null,zero, or undefined)